# Celery tasks profiling

Tags: python, profiling, celery, django-celery

As I can see in `top` utility `celery` procecess consume a lot of CPU time. So I want to profile it.

I can do it manually on developer machine like so:

```
python -m cProfile -o test-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%T`.prof ./manage.py celeryd -B
```

But to have accurate timings I need to profile it on production machine. On that machine (Fedora 14) celery is launched by init scripts. E.g.

```
service celeryd start
```

I have figured out these scripts eventually call `manage.py celeryd_multi` eventually. So my question is how can I tell `celeryd_multi` to start celery with profiling enabled? In my case this means add `-m cProfile -o out.prof` options to `python`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're confusing two separate issues. You could be processing too many individual tasks or an individual task could be inefficient.

You may know which of these is the problem, but it's not clear from your question which it is.

To track how many tasks are being processed I suggest you look at [celerymon](https://github.com/ask/celerymon). If a particular task appears more often that you would expect then you can investigate where it is getting called from.

Profiling the whole of celery is probably not helpful as you'll get lots of code that you have no control over. As you say it also means you have a problem running it in production. I suggest you look at adding the [profiling code](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) directly into your task definition.

You can use `cProfile.run('func()')` as a layer of indirection between celery and your code so each run of the task is profiled. If you generate a unique filename and pass it as the second parameter to `run` you'll have a directory full of profile data that you can inspect on a task-by-task basis, or use [pstats.add](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.add) to combine multiple task runs together.

Finally, per-task profiling means you can also turn profiling on or off using a setting in your project code either globally or by task, rather than needing to modify the init scripts on your server.

Comment: `celerymon` is not maintained now.