# Profile a celery task using cProfile

Tags: django, celery, profiling, cprofile

I've a django app which runs some asynchronous tasks in the background with celery. I'd like to profile the tasks running inside the celery worker. I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931377/how-can-we-profile-memory-usage-of-each-celery-task) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473537/celery-tasks-profiling#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20cProfile.,task%20basis%2C%20or%20use%20pstats.) but they weren't very useful. How do I profile a specific celery task in a django app?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can solve your issue with this package
https://pypi.org/project/django-cprofile-middleware/

Moreover ref this to understand basics of profiling
http://www.gilles-bertrand.com/2012/11/profiling-python-code-with-celery.html?m=1